# How to assign N numbers into M pack that minimize some target function?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, np-complete, integer-programming

I have N(for example 30) integer numbers `V[i]`, and M(for example 8) packs, each pack
have an expected value `P[j]`.

I want to assign each integer number to one pack, the following expression calculate the difference
between the sum of `V[k]` that in pack `j` and the expected value of pack `j`.

```
diff[j] = abs(P[j] - sum(V[k] that in pack j))
```

The target is to find the best solution that minimize `sum(diff[j])`.

I don't know what's the type of this kind of problem. Can this be solved by Linear programming, or is it a NP-Complete problem?

Comment: I doubt this is what you meant, but I should point out that "linear programming" and "NP-Complete" do not come close to partitioning the problem space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether this is NP-hard or not, you may be able to efficiently solve your problem for the problem instances you need using easily accessible integer programming software. For your problem, you could define x_{ij} to define if X[i] is assigned to group j. You would then also define variables d_j, which are the diff[j] in your formulation. Then your model is:

```
min_{x, d} \sum_{j=1}^M d_j
s.t.       d_j >= P[j] - \sum_{i=1}^N X[i]x_{ij} \forall j
           d_j >= \sum_{i=1}^N X[i]x_{ij} - P[j] \forall j
           \sum_{j=1}^M x_ij = 1 \forall i
           x_{ij}\in \{0, 1\}
```

This is a mixed integer optimization model, which can be solved, for instance, using the `lpsolve` or `lpSolveAPI` packages in R or the `intlinprog` function in MATLAB.

Comment: GLPK ain't too bad either.

Answer (score 0):

I can prove that your problem is NP by reducing another NP problem to this one. In other words, I'll show that if I can answer this problem, I can immediately answer another NP problem.

The specific problem I'll be reducing is the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem):

Let `V` be the set of numbers. We want to know if `sum(V)==0`. Let `P={0}` (a length-one array containing only `0`). In this situation, the optimal solution to your problem has `sum(diff[j])==0` if and only if the subset sum is `0`. In other words, the Subset Sum Problem is a special case of your problem, so your problem is at least as hard as the Subset Sum Problem.

Therefore, your problem is NP. I'm still not sure if it's NP-Complete.

Comment: I need to assign all the numbers to one pack, if there is only one pack, then the `sum(diff[j])` is `sum(V) - P[0]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but I added a sentence to try to explain my answer better.

Comment: Does the specific problem has only one pack? For example there five numbers `[1,2,3,4,5]`, and one pack `[12]`, the there is only one choice, the different is `1+2+3+4+5 - 12 = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is NP-hard by reduction from [2-partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (2P). Change the current problem to a decision problem asking if sum(diff[j])=0. Given an instance of 2P, let `P[0] = P[1] = sum(V)/2`. If there exists a two partitioning, then there clearly exists some assignment with `sum(diff[j])=0`.

There is a psuedo-polytime algorithm for 2-partition, but it's not likely to work for this problem since it doesn't apply to >=3-partitions.

It appears as if this is analogous to bin-packing, but I'm not 100% sure because you can overflow a 'pack' but not a 'bin'.